# Batch script to run multiple wget commands

Tags: windows, scripting

I'm trying to create a script that has multiple wget commands that include site credentials to download a file. If I run the wget command individually in a command prompt, the file downloads properly.

If I create a batch script to include multiple wget commands, none of the files download properly. I'm not proficient in scripting and haven't found a solution online. Is it possible to run multiple wget commands within a batch file?

This is an example of my batch script.

```
 q@echo off
FOR /F "TOKENS=1* DELIMS= " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET CDATE=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 eol=/ DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET mm=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 DELIMS=/ eol=/" %%A IN ('echo %CDATE%') DO SET dd=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=2,3 DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('echo %CDATE%') DO SET yyyy=%%B
SET date=%yyyy%%mm%%dd%


wget -v --http-user="username" --http-password=password "http://server/dira/file:format=PDF" -O "C:\test\%date%file.pdf"

wget -v --http-user="username" --http-password=password "http://server/dirb/file2:format=PDF" -O "C:\test\%date%file.pdf"
```

Comment: what does "none of the files download properly" mean? any errors?

Comment: They download "corrupted" with 0k in size.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the URLs you are wanting to download from you could store the download files or URLs in a text file then use the `wget -i` option

This question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/374053/downloading-multiple-files-with-wget-and-handling-parameters) posted on SuperUser may help out as well

Comment: The challenge I came across with this option is that I need to rename the file being downloaded to have today's date appended to it. Each file had a different name and didn't follow any numerical structure such as file1, file2, file3, etc.

Comment: So are you trying to download multiple PDF files from a specific site then?  Cause if so you can set to download all files of that type from a website with wget as well.  I noticed you said they downloads were corrupt, have you tried your script out elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use PowerShell.

```
#Feel free to modify date format via google search
$dateString = Get-Date -f MM-dd-yy
$client = New-Object System.Net.Webclient
$client.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("user","pass")


"File1.pdf","File2.pdf","file3.zip" | % {
    $path = "http://somesite.com/files/" + $_
    $fileName =  "C:\downloads\" + ($_).Replace(".zip",($dateString + ".zip"))
    $client.DownloadFile($path,$fileName)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If one wants to download multiple files using wget the best way is to add "start" to at beginning of every line. Like:

```
start wget -v --http-user="username" --http-password=password "http://server/dira/file:format=PDF" -O "C:\test\%date%file.pdf
```

If one wants to avoid each line opening a new cmd window use /B option. Like:

```
start /B wget -v --http-user="username" --http-password=password "http://server/dira/file:format=PDF" -O "C:\test\%date%file.pdf
```